# «Желтый, красный, голубой, Не угнаться за тобой»

Tags: морфология, синтаксический-разбор

> Мой
> Веселый,
> Звонкий
> Мяч,
> Ты куда
> Помчался
> Вскачь?
> **Желтый,
>
> Красный,
>
> Голубой**,
> Не угнаться
> За тобой!
> [С. Я. Маршак. Мяч](https://peskarlib.ru/samuil-marshak/myach/)

Какой частью речи являются *жёлтый, красный, голубой*?

Comment: Не поняла, в чём вопрос.Что, кроме прилагательного, ещё чем-то может быть? Или Вы хотели спросить, каким членом предложения является? Тогда сказуемым в неполном контекстном предложении.

Answer (score 3):

**Ответ исправлен!**

**Мой весёлый звонкий** мяч, Ты куда помчался вскачь?  **Желтый, красный, голубой** (мяч), Не угнаться за тобой.

Второй ряд определений относится к пропущенному слову "мяч", которое является повтором обращения, поэтому фактически **желтый, красный, голубой** в качестве определения входит в обращение.

Интересная конструкция, **что-то вроде расчлененного обращения.**

Пример расчлененного обращения:    Откуда, **умная**, бредёшь ты, **голова**?

Answer (score 0):

Являются прилагательными как частью речи.

Как член предложения.
Конкретно в данном предложении могут являться:

и обращением (если подразумевается обращение к мячу через описание его свойств). Не является членом предложения.

и однородными определениями (если описывать всё предложения как сложное, то первая его часть, состоящая из трёх прилагательных, будет неполным повествовательным утвердительным предложением. А три прилагательных - однородными определениями).

Таким образом, всё зависит от интонации прочтения этого стихотворения И (!) мнения учителя.

Answer (score 0):

Хочу предложить еще одно, как мне кажется, возможное решение.
*Желтый, красный, голубой* — это, конечно же, прилагательные.
В предложении из стихотворения они являются обращением и употреблены как существительные (желтый, красный, голубой — то есть разноцветный). Этот прием называется [окказиональной субстантивацией](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F), при которой переход происходит только в определенном контексте (известнейший пример: "Толстый и тонкий" А. П. Чехова).

*— Эй, Жёлтый, ты что там творишь? – спросил Синий Луч с нетерпением* (А. Дубровина. Лучи).

[«Жёлтый, это меню»](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mP8q-coeNWk)